# Return column names if contains all zeros or NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0, np.NaN, 0], [0, 0, np.NaN, 0]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
print(df)
```

Out:

```
   a  b   c  d
0  1  0 NaN  0
1  0  0 NaN  0
```

I would like to get the columns names (`b`, `c`, and `d` for case above) if all its values are **Zeros** or **NaNs**, how could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks.

To subset zeros columns:

```
df.loc[:, ~(df != 0).any(axis=0)]
```

Out:

```
   b  d
0  0  0
1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `.any()` to detect `null` and `0`

```py
>>> df
   a  b   c  d
0  1  0 NaN  0
1  0  0 NaN  0
>>> df.any()
a     True
b    False
c    False
d    False
dtype: bool
```

You can use this as-is, or call `.to_dict()` to create a pure-Python mapping

```
>>> df.any().to_dict()
{'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': False, 'd': False}
```

---

EDIT: Original Answer (incorrect)

This is a rare case where you should iterate over the DataFrame as you're interested in the columns, not the rows

```py
na_or_0_cols = []
for column in df:  # iterates by-name
    if df[column].isna().all() or (df[column] == 0).all():
        na_or_0_cols.append(column)
print(na_or_0_cols)
```

Out:

```
['b', 'c', 'd']
```

(this doesn't work because it won't detect both)

Comment: You omit the case if all values are zeros in the last chunk of your code.